# Flattenspec for nested json column in a csv file

Tags: apache-nifi, druid

I had a csv file in that there is a tag column for that column there is a nested json data, now I have to flatten those data and ingest it into druid data source.

Basically tags data are got like string data like- "key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"
I have added the {} using concat function in druid.
Now after doing this I have to do flatten.
I want to do flatten this converted json data.

I want sub string data as a column.